# Почему не записывается автор комментария?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, комментарии

Всем привет!
Есть вот такая функция и она записывает данные в бд, но не записывает только значение из переменной **$authorComments**. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть дело?

```
$authorComments = $_SESSION['USER_NAME'];

function addComments() {
    global $authorComments;
    $page_id = $_POST["page_id"];
    $text_comment = $_POST["text_comment"];
    $author = htmlspecialchars($author);
    $text_comment = htmlspecialchars($text_comment);
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "forum");
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`author`, `page_id`, `text_comment`, `regdate`) VALUES ('$authorComments', '$page_id', '$text_comment', NOW())");// Добавляем комментарий в таблицу
}
if (isset($_POST['sendcomment'])) {
    addComments();
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);// Делаем реридект обратно
}
```

Comment: Во первых не используйте `global` и берите из сессии значение прямо в функции. Во вторых проверьте, есть ли оно там вообще через `var_dump($_SESSION['USER_NAME'])`

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, вызывается ли session_start() перед этим кодом. Если оно не вызывается, то $_SESSION['USER_NAME'] не будет существовать, и поэтому в $authorComments будет пустое значение (null).